# Python strptime errors on parsing strftime output

Tags: python, strptime, strftime

I am trying to store a date in a human readable format. For that I save and read back a string containing a date. I am using `date.min` to denote a date before any other.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

d = date.min
s = datetime.strftime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(s) 
# 1-01-01

d2 = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
# ValueError: time data '1-01-01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

However, when I try to parse the date using `strptime` that was output by `strftime`, I only get an error. It seems that `strptime` is expecting leading zeros like `0001`, which strftime is not outputting.

It might be possible to use `None`. Are there any other ways to work around what seems like a bug to me?

Comment: I'm not getting an error on 3.9, what python version are you on? Also why do you use the `format` method?

Comment: I am using version 3.8.5. What other method would you suggest I use?

Comment: I get no error with your code as well.  It generates `0001-01-01` not `1-01-01` (Python 3.9).  Also `s=f'{date.min:%Y-%m-%d}'` is a more directly way of creating the string.

Comment: The `format` method you have is redundant, `s = datetime.strftime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")` is enough

Comment: @MarkTolonen it's platform dependent. I get `1` on linux but `0001` on windows

Comment: @Nick that's not what the [Python documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).  Bug in implementation or bug in documentation...

Comment: @MarkTolonen There's a [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue13305) on it

Comment: @Nick Thank you, I was looking for the bug report.

Comment: Don't thank me thank the answerer...

Comment: @Nick I just noticed that...also that documentation says %Y does 0001, etc., but found the note further down that it is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add leading zeros:

try replacing:

```
s = {datetime.strftime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")}
```

with:

```
s = f'{d.year:04d}-{datetime.strftime(d, "%m-%d")}'
```

If you want to work with dates easily, I can really suggest the 'Arrow' library.
https://pypi.org/project/arrow/

Comment: Both answers work, but I find this way of padding a bit more elegant. Or use an updated Python version with the bug fixed.

Comment: I like @mhawke solution as it does not involve any formatting

Comment: @DanielGilon: thankyou, you might consider upvoting then :)

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.9 on Linux exhibits the problem as expected in the many comments on the question. One workaround that should work on all platforms is to use ISO format for the date string with [`date.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.date.isoformat):

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> s = date.min.isoformat()
>>> s
'0001-01-01'
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> assert d.date() == date.min
```

You can also use [`date.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.date.fromisoformat) instead of `strptime()`:

```
>>> date.fromisoformat(date.min.isoformat())
datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strftime` can't add leading zeros to the year. It calls the underlying C function and its behavior on adding leading zeros to the year is [platform specific](https://bugs.python.org/issue32195). You can work around this by formatting the date object by yourself. Just do a check if `d.year` is less than 1000 and add how many leading zeros needed:

```py
d = date.min
year_str = ''.join(['0' for _ in range(4 - len(str(d.year)))]) + str(d.year)
s = '{year}-{md}'.format(year=year_str, md=datetime.strftime(d, "%m-%d"))
d2 = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
# now d2 is equal to datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```